# AngularFire2 typings: "Property 'take' does not exist on type 'FirebaseObjectObservable<any>'"

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I've updated my ionic app from beta 11 to rc0. So it means I've switched from typescript 1.8 to 2.

I've configured AngularFire2 according to this site
[Getting Started with Ionic 2 RC0, Firebase 3 + AngularFire 2](https://playcode.org/getting-started-with-ionic-2-rc0-firebase-3-angularfire-2/)

I had this line of code working:

```
this.af.database.object(`comments/${commentId}`).take(1).subscribe({
    data => console.log(data)
});
```

But now getting this error

> error TS2339: Property 'take' does not exist on type
>   'FirebaseObjectObservable'.

Any ideas on what's going on? How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you importing the rxjs take operator using:  
`import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';`

Comment: Thanks! It solved the issue :)

Comment: You can post the answer and I'll accept it as the solution.

Comment: I imported the operator but am still getting the error message :(

Answer (score 6):

For more recents versions of rxjs (v6) and angularfire (v5), the syntax I used is :

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators'

...

this.afAuth.authState.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(user => {
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting user @codedesignr's answer from above so this question can have an official solution:

> Import the rxjs take operator using: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';`

Answer (score 1):

If your angular version is 6 and above.

use below:

import { take, map } from "rxjs/operators";

Install - npm install --save rxjs-compat

Also use pipe with other functions(Take, Map).

timer(0, 10) .pipe(take(1000)) .pipe(map(() => x));

Answer (score 1):

this.auth.authState.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(user=>{

});